# CSS3 transition bottom up

Tags: css, css-transitions

Got stuck here: http://jsfiddle.net/UFkg8/

Right now the animation is top-down. What do I need to change to make it bottom-up?

If I change top to 100%; in .mask then it works but it also doubles the div's height and creates a scrollbar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've seen that you don't want to modify the `.post`, but why not add `overflow:hidden;` to it? [This jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/UFkg8/1/) works for me (at least it does in Chrome).

Comment: Bingo, thanks. I can't modify it because it's some inline style injected from a jquery plugin, I c/p it from the html markup. I can override/add things to it though. I'll just add overflow:hidden; to the .post class in the css. :D